# OAuth 2.0 Client ID and Secret Java implementation

Tags: java, authentication, oauth-2.0, client

I have been asked to make an `OAuth 2.0` integration with an external company. All they need from me is to provide them with are client ID and client secret, and authorize their access if the details are correct.

Is there a simple library that does it, or maybe an implementation guide?

Answer (score 1):

use https://auth0.com or Onelogin - https://developers.onelogin.com . both of them provide Oauth2.0 and enormous amount of documentation and samples.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring, I recommend you to try [Spring Security](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security) + [Spring Security OAuth 2.0 client](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-oauth2-client). [Here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/) you can see how to configure these libraries correctly. Customization of OAuth2 if needed you can see [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests).